# Need to configure javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1 with project

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am trying to configure javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1 and api with my java project, Please inform as to how to perform this action. i am using eclipse kepler entrprise edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Right Click on your project, Configur Build Path and add external Jar file and browse to where your jar file is and add to your project if that what you are looking for